# Wrong header in an unumbered chapter after list of tables

Tags: header-footer, titles, books

I am facing a rather weird bug, in book class. After the `listoftebles` I am writing an unumbered chapter. The header of this chapter isn't it's title, but list of tables' title.

[image]

My code is

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
 \tableofcontents
 \listoffigures
 \listoftables
 \chapter*{Unumbered Chapter}
 \lipsum[1-2]
 \part{First part}
 \chapter{First Chapter}
 \lipsum[1]
 \begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics{fig1}
  \caption{Title}
 \end{figure}
 \begin{table}
 \begin{tabular}{ l c r }
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
  4 & 5 & 6 \\
  7 & 8 & 9 \\
\end{tabular}
\caption{Table}
\end{table}
 \chapter{Second Chapter}
 \lipsum[2]
 \begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics{fig1}
  \caption{Title}
 \end{figure}
 \part{Second part}
 \chapter{Third Chapter}
 \begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics{fig1}
  \caption{Title}
 \end{figure}
 \lipsum[3]
 \chapter{Fourth Chapter}
 \lipsum[4]
 \begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics{fig1}
  \caption{Title}
 \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Any idea on why is this happening and how can it be fixed?

Comment: Quick and dirty solution after `\listoftables`: `\markboth{}{}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `book` class provides `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` to separate these two chunks. If you use them as in

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\chapter{Unumbered Chapter}
\lipsum[1-2]

\mainmatter

\part{First part}

\chapter{First Chapter}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{fig1}
\caption{Title}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{ l c r }
1 & 2 & 3 \\
4 & 5 & 6 \\
7 & 8 & 9 \\
\end{tabular}
\caption{Table}
\end{table}

\chapter{Second Chapter}
\lipsum[2]

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{fig1}
\caption{Title}
\end{figure}

\part{Second part}
\chapter{Third Chapter}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{fig1}
\caption{Title}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[3]

\chapter{Fourth Chapter}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{fig1}
\caption{Title}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

then the problem won't appear. Note `\chapter` and not `\chapter*`.

However, this will use Roman numerals for the front matter. If you don't want it, but prefer continuous numbering, just add to the preamble

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\frontmatter}{\cleardoublepage\@mainmatterfalse}
\renewcommand{\mainmatter}{\cleardoublepage\@mainmattertrue}
\makeatother
```